# How to get secure token from iCloud calendar login authentication?

Tags: ios, calendar, icloud, icalendar, icloud-api

I am developing application in which i have to connect multiple iCloud calendar. i don't want to use EventKit. Application like [Sunrise](https://calendar.sunrise.am/) , Doing same thing. I have gone through many documentation related to iCloud but not able to find way to get secure access token from iCloud Login. Here is quote from apple **[iCloud security and privacy](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202303)**

> **Use of secure tokens for authentication**
>
> When you access iCloud services using Apple’s built-in apps (for example, Mail, Contacts, and Calendar apps on iOS or OS X), authentication is handled using a secure token. Using secure tokens eliminates the need to store your iCloud password on devices and computers. Even if you choose to use a third-party application to access your iCloud data, your username and password are sent over an encrypted SSL connection.

How to send appleId and password over SSL connection ?

Which Api should I use ?

Comment: Want to know if you were able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: We have took support from apple but they denied by saying "not possible"..